# Laravel Multiple Inputs Search 4.2

Tags: laravel, search, input

I am making a multiple inputs search query and i need help cause i do not know how to exactly to do this i have read all the documentation and i  did not understand it.Now i am stuck in the controller.....

Also i would really appreciate of how to call the informations that i want in in the ***show.blade*** ! Thank you for any help !

**Index blade**

```
 <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div><h4></h4></div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                {{ Form::open(array('action' => array('UserController@search'), 'class'=>'form width88', 'role'=>'search', 'method' => 'GET')) }}
                <div id="prefetch">
                    {{ Form::text('name', null, array('class' => 'typeahead form-group form-control', 'placeholder' => 'name...')) }}
                    {{ Form::text('lastname', null, array('class' => 'form-group form-control', 'placeholder' => 'lastname...')) }}
                    {{--     {{ Form::text('id', null, array('class' => 'form-group form-control', 'placeholder' => 'id...')) }}
                        {{ Form::text('user-seminars', null, array('class' => 'form-group form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Class tha is enrolled...')) }}
                        {{ Form::text('user-class', null, array('class' => 'form-group form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Class that belongs...')) }}
                        {{ Form::text('user-annex', null, array('class' => 'form-group form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Department that belongs...')) }}
                        {{ Form::text('type', null, array('class' => 'form-group form-control', 'placeholder' => 'User type...')) }}
                        {{ Form::text('date_created', null, array('class' => 'form-group form-control', 'placeholder' => 'date created account...')) }}
                        {{ Form::text('date_enrolled', null, array('class' => 'form-group form-control', 'placeholder' => 'date enrolled in class...')) }}
```

**routes**

```
Route::get('users/index', 'UserController@index');
        Route::get('users/search', 'UserController@search');
        Route::get('users/show', 'UserController@show');
```

**UserContoller**

```
 public function index(){

    return View::make('user.index');
}

public function search(){

    return View::make('user.show');

    }

public function show(){

    return View::make('user.show');

}
```

**USERS TABLE**

> id , firstname,last_name,etc etc etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function search(Request $request){   
   $users = App\User::where('firstname',$request->name)
             ->orWhere('lastname',$request->lastname)
             ->orWhere('id',$request->id)
             // more orWhere Clause
             ->get();

    return View::make('user.show',compact('users'));

}

public function show($id){
    $user = App\User::find($id);

    return View::make('user.show',compact('user'));
}
```

Why are you using return View::make('user.show') to render two different resources?

Comment: i will try this and get back to you

Comment: thax u man yes i dont need two time the return view::make it was from experimenting ^_^ and i forgot it !

Answer (score 0):

the first thing i see its the form action

**your code**

```
 {{ Form::open(array('action' => array('UserController@search'), 'class'=>'form width88', 'role'=>'search', 'method' => 'GET')) }}
```

**should be**

```
 {{ Form::open(array('action' => array('users/search'), 'class'=>'form width88', 'role'=>'search', 'method' => 'GET')) }}
```

the controller is the fun part. if you're looking for all the inputs to be required you should validate it first

```
//first we set the inputs rultes
$data = Input::all();
$rules = array(
      'name'     => 'required',
      'lastname' => 'required',
      //rest of the inputs  that are required

);
//then we use the validator method
$val = Validator::make($data,$rules);
if($val->fails())
{
      /*redirect to the form again, you can set errors with session 
        or ->withError($validator)*/
      return Redirect::back();
}
then you make your query
$user = User::where('name','=',$data['name'])
        ->where('lastname','=',$data['lastname'])
        //more where('field','=','value')
        ->get();
```

if the fields arent required you only make the query with

```
$user = User::where('name','=',$data['name'])
        ->orWhere('lastname','=',$data['lastname'])
        //more orWhere('field','=','value')
        ->get();
```

and finally you return your result to the view like:

```
return View::make('user.show')->with('user',$user);
```

Comment: thank you for aswering but i dont think i need to do all that i take the information i need from your answer and i will try it to see the results !